# Advantages and Disadvantages of making a variable class level vs final local

Tags: java, variables, scope

I have been coding in Java for some time now and I have to make a decision on whether or not to make a variable class level vs making a final local variable so I have scope on it within my code. Is there a standard or logic to make this decision? Are there any pros and cons for doing it a certain way?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: The scope which you need to access it should determine the decision. Make your variables only accessible, where you need them. I think I do net get your question totally. Please add a code example.

Comment: so is for specific problems, for more nebulous questions such as this try http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, you're better off using the most restrictive scoping possible.  The reason is that it prevents poorly written users of your class from messing with its internals and causing bugs.

If I were you I'd make all variables private final and local, if possible.  If you must make it non-final, keep it private and only allow access to it through setter methods (and getters, of course).

You can always open up the scope later if you need to, but it is much harder to lock down an attribute once it's out there and in use.

For a more in-depth explanation, see [Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC)'s "Minimize the accessibility of classes and members" and "Favor immutability".  A classic read